# Boas práticas com testes PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

Estou começando em testes, e queria saber se estou seguindo corretamente, uso laravel, e tive alguns dilemas para desenvolver um teste de um `service` que tenho. Ele faz algumas operações num app via API, só que como não tenho como fazer um "mock" dessa api eu tive que fazer o teste "sequencial" ( em produção )para poder usar os valores que usava antes:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;


use App\Exceptions\AppConnectionException;
use App\Exceptions\AppErrorException;
use App\Exceptions\AppNullException;
use App\Services\App\AppService;
use App\Services\App\Responses\Card;
use Tests\TestCase;

class AppServiceTest extends TestCase
{
  /** @var AppService */
  private $appService;
  /** @var int */
  private $pipeId,$destinationPhase;

  protected function setUp(): void {
    parent::setUp();
    $this->appService = new AppService();
    $this->pipeId = 533822;
    $this->destinationPhase = 3656118;

  }

  /**
   * @test
   * @throws AppConnectionException
   * @throws AppErrorException
   * @throws AppNullException
   */
  public function test(){
//  CREATE
    $title = 'teste '. now()->toTimeString();
    $fields = ['nome_completo'=>'igor'];

    $card = $this->appService->createCard($this->pipeId,$title,$fields);
    $this->assertInstanceOf(Card::class,$card);
    $this->assertEquals($title,$card->title);

//  SHOW CARD
    $card = $this->appService->showCard($card->id);
    $this->assertInstanceOf(Card::class,$card);
    $this->assertIsArray($card->rawData); // TODO: melhorar acerto verificando os fields criados acima

//    UPDATE FIELD
    $fielid = array_keys($fields)[0];
    $newvalue = $fielid . " updated";
    $mutation = $this->appService->updateField($card->id,$fielid,$newvalue);
    $this->assertTrue($mutation);

//    MOVE CARD
    $card = $this->appService->moveCardToPhase($card->id,$this->destinationPhase);
    $this->assertInstanceOf(Card::class,$card);
    $this->assertEquals($card->currentPhase['id'],$this->destinationPhase);

  }

}
```

Eu imagino que cada teste deve ser individual, certo ? esta sequencia é muito errado ?

Answer (score 2):

Para melhorar estes testes é mais indicado separá-los em vários métodos, assim tudo fica mais organizado e é possível ter uma noção melhor de tudo que está sendo testado. Segue a classe refeita:

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;


use App\Exceptions\AppConnectionException;
use App\Exceptions\AppErrorException;
use App\Exceptions\AppNullException;
use App\Services\App\AppService;
use App\Services\App\Responses\Card;
use Tests\TestCase;

class AppServiceTest extends TestCase
{

  private $appService;
  private $pipeId;
  private $destinationPhase;
  private $card;
  private $fields;

  protected function setUp(): void
  {

    parent::setUp();
    $this->appService       = new AppService();
    $this->pipeId           = 533822;
    $this->destinationPhase = 3656118;
    $this->fields           = ['nome_completo'=>'igor'];
   
  }

  public function testCardCreation(): void
  {
    
     $title      = 'teste '. now()->toTimeString();
     $this->card = $this->appService->createCard($this->pipeId, $title, $this->fields);

     $this->assertInstanceOf(Card::class, $this->card);
     $this->assertEquals($title, $this->card->title);

  }
  
  public function testShowCard(): void
  {

     $card = $this->appService->showCard($this->card->id);

     $this->assertInstanceOf(Card::class, $card);
     $this->assertIsArray($card->rawData); // TODO: melhorar acerto verificando os fields criados acima

  }
    
  public function testCardUpdate(): void
  {

    
     $fielid   = array_keys($this->fields)[0];
     $newvalue = $fielid . " updated";
     $mutation = $this->appService->updateField($this->card->id, $fielid, $newvalue);

     $this->assertTrue($mutation);
    
  }

  public function testCardMove(): void
  {

     $card = $this->appService->moveCardToPhase($this->card->id, $this->destinationPhase);

     $this->assertInstanceOf(Card::class, $card);
     $this->assertEquals($card->currentPhase['id'], $this->destinationPhase);

  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Começa dividindo o teste em testes menores, pra ficar mais fácil de visualizar:

```
public function testCreate(){
    // code
  }

  public function testShowCard(){
    // code
  }

  public function testUpdateField(){
    // code
  }
  function testMoveCard(){
    // code
  }
```

A partir daí começa a definir atributos pra sua classe de testes, e, para definí-los, crie uma função chamada `setUp` (ela será chamada antes de cada teste).

Em caso de dúvidas, sempre se lembre: cada função deve ser responsável por testar **UMA** funcionalidade do projeto. Aí fica mais fácil de verificar em qual funcionalidade o erro ocorreu. E leia a documentação do [`PHPUnit`](https://phpunit.de/documentation.html) e do [`Laravel`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database-testing) para aprimorar os testes.

Bons estudos ;)